# Cannot address specific URL with React Router Dom

Tags: javascript, reactjs, apache, react-router-dom

I think I understand the issue that I am running into but I really am not sure of what solution
I should use.

I am creating a site using React with a couple of different pages like `/about`, `/support`, `/contact`, etc.

I used create-react-app to create my project and am using react-router-dom for routing.

Everything works fine if you are linked to a base URL and then use the navigational elements to navigate to the specific views. My issue is that if I try to go directly to `mysite.com/about` I get a 404 error.

This page on the CRA docs explains my error:
https://create-react-app.dev/docs/deployment/#serving-apps-with-client-side-routing

I understand why the issue is occuring, I just don't know enough about back  end to fix it. I am using Siteground.com for hosting and I know they use Apache but I'm not sure what specific type or how I would go about interfacing with that. I tried created the described `.htaccess` file in my public folder but it didn't change much.

If anyone can point me in the direction of a solution that would be great. Maybe I should just not use React Router Dom? Can post any code that is needed!

Thanks!